# Java GWT JSONObject put String

Tags: java, string, gwt, json

How to create json object and put my values in it in GWT?

```
import com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject;
...
JSONObject myJson = new JSONObject();
myJson.put("hello", "world");
```

Because at put method I've receive that error:
**The method put(String, JSONValue) in the type JSONObject is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)**

Answer (score 1):

```
myJson.put("hello", new JSONString("world"));
```